# Adding Newline Character to Rascal Syntax Definition

Tags: rascal

How do I add a newline character as part of Rascal’s Syntax Definition. I tried this but it doesn’t seem work.

```
syntax Entity
   =  @Foldable entity: "entity" Id name  "{"  {Field “\n”}+ fields "}"
;

syntax Field 
   = field: Id name ":" Type t ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would add a `layout` definition in scope, like so:

```
layout Whitespace = [\ \n\t\r]* !>> [\ \n\t\r];
```

After this is added, the other rules are augmented with the `Whitespace` non-terminal everywhere before the parser is generated.

For example, internally `Field+` becomes `{Field Whitespace}+` en `Field` becomes `Id name Whitespace ":" Whitespace Type t`.

So that adds `Whitespace` **in between** all the symbols. To be able to accept newlines and spaces also before and after the top-non-terminal add `start` to it:

`start syntax TranslationUnit = Entity*;`

This will add this rule automatically:

`syntax start[TranslationUnit] = Whitespace {Entity Whitespace}* Whitespace;`